# Vue Filtered Object Array by month

Tags: vue.js

Have a Objects:

```
    {
      "id": 1766013,
      "created_date": "2019-01-28 12:54:23",
      "amount": 10000,
      "type": "payin",
      "status": "done",
      "method": "m_visamc"
    },
    {
      "id": 1766012,
      "created_date": "2019-03-28 12:54:08",
      "amount": 300000,
      "type": "payin",
      "status": "error",
      "method": "m_visamc"
    },
    {
      "id": 1766011,
      "created_date": "2019-02-28 12:53:31",
      "amount": 6000,
      "type": "payin",
      "status": "done",
      "method": "m_visamc"
    }
```

How I can group items by month, by value in "created_date"?
Need get items just one month

Thank you

Comment: what is your expected value shown?

Comment: One array this items of this month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand you correctly you want to group your items by the month value which is stored in the property `created_date`. The following code will do that for you.

```js
var items = [
{
  "id": 1766013,
  "created_date": "2019-01-28 12:54:23",
  "amount": 10000,
  "type": "payin",
  "status": "done",
  "method": "m_visamc"
},
{
  "id": 1766012,
  "created_date": "2019-03-28 12:54:08",
  "amount": 300000,
  "type": "payin",
  "status": "error",
  "method": "m_visamc"
},
{
  "id": 1766011,
  "created_date": "2019-02-28 12:53:31",
  "amount": 6000,
  "type": "payin",
  "status": "done",
  "method": "m_visamc"
},
{
  "id": 1766012,
  "created_date": "2019-02-26 12:53:36",
  "amount": 6000,
  "type": "payin",
  "status": "done",
  "method": "m_visamc"
}];

var groupByCreatedDateMonth = array =>
 array.reduce((objectsByKeyValue, obj) => {
     var dateString = obj.created_date;
            var date = new Date(dateString);
            var value = date.getMonth();
      
     objectsByKeyValue[value] = (objectsByKeyValue[value] || []).concat(obj);
     return objectsByKeyValue;
 }, {});
            
var result = groupByCreatedDateMonth(items);

console.log(result);
```